# adb shell mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system Operation not permitted

Tags: android, linux

i have put this command but facing this problem

Operation not permitted

```
 adb shell mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system
```

and this error is shown

```
Operation not permitted
```

Comment: that would be because you are not permitted (as you are not root) to perform this operation of remounting the single most important partition on the system that would allow you to modify all kind of critical files and properties.

Comment: http://piotrbuda.eu/2012/05/installing-google-play-on-android-emulator.html

Comment: I run Root Checker app, and it tells me that my device has root access.  Yet, I still get this error...

Answer (score 1):

You have to be a `root` to remount `/system`.

Check is this true by `id` command.

I guess you have only permissions of user-`shell`

**add**
If you are really root - you may try `adb remount` command. This command is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: remount failed: Operation not permitted

Comment: What should we look for in the 'id' command?  Mine spits out: 
id
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=1003(graphics),1004(input),1007(log),1009(mount),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(s
dcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats) context=u:r:adbd:s0

Comment: user `shell` is not permitted to remount `/system`. You need root access.

Comment: Try `adb root` and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

What I found worked for me on a rooted device

> adb shell
>
> su
>
> abd mount -o remount,rw {whatever options you want}

su didn't ask for a password

Answer (score 0):

If you have rooted phone then go to terminal and hit the below command to get all access

mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

This helped me